# How to set Angular Material Fields to width:100%?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-flex-layout

How should I set form fields to max width with a screen size under 840px?

I'm using: Angular, Angular Materials & Flex-Layout.

Specifically, why doesn't this work & what should I use instead?

**Styles.css:**

```
@media (max-width: 840px) {
  md-form-field{
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you set rules in wrong css file, like in `styles.css`. If need to set styles there, turn off ViewEncapsulation:

```
import { ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
```

Comment: This was it, moving the css rule into a file referenced in the relevant components worked fine. I still don't understand how the material css imported to styles.css can be applied while manual css rules cannot.